# Synchronized using for Methods in Java?

Tags: java

I need to know about the usage of **Synchronized using for methods in java**.Please see the below code once.

Code :

```
public void upDateAllUsersStatus(UserDetails userDetails)
{


    for(Player p : userDetails.getPlayersList())
    {
        if(p != null)
        {
            String userId = p.getUserId();
            upDateUserStatus(userId );
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void upDateUserStatus(String name)
{           
    //here update status of user in db.
}
```

The above code used `synchronized`for method.is there any possibility of getting **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException** using synchronized above upDateUserStatus()?

Can you please suggest me what is the use of synchronized using for above method?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `if(p != null)` looks like an unnecessary bit of superstitious coding that should be removed. If there are nulls in your list, fix the code that's putting nulls in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `upDateUserStatus` modifies the list of players stored in its `userDetails` object, the next iteration of the loop in `upDateAllUsersStatus` may throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because the player list was modified (by `upDateUserStatus`) while it's being iterated (by `upDateAllUsersStatus`).  The `synchronized` keyword doesn't help:  that protects against concurrent execution in different threads, but it doesn't prevent an individual thread from modifying a list while that same thread is iterating it.

Your code looks strange, though, and I suspect it has other problems:  you're iterating the list of players stored in `userDetails`, but you don't actually *do* anything with the individual `Player` objects.  You just call `upDateUserStatus` multiple times on the same `userDetails` object.  Did you intend for `upDateUserStatus` to take a `Player` argument instead of a `UserDetails`?  If so, that should be safe, since an individual `Player` (presumably) can't modify the list of other players.

Comment: yes,Check once my code and please suggest me once again.@Wyzard